# mongodb backup role error to query system.profile

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo user with backup role, when running mongodump, I got the following error:

```
014-06-13T14:10:53.226-0400    test.system.profile to /backup/mongodb/06-13-2014/test/system.profile.bson
assertion: 11010 count fails:{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "not authorized on test to execute command { count: "system.profile", query: {} }", code: 13 }
```

Here is the user setting:

```
"_id" : "admin.backupAdmin",
    "user" : "backupAdmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
           "role" : "backup",
           "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
```

any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone still have problem with that. This is a bug in MongoDB bult-in roles: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21724

If you don't want to update, here is an online fix without granting dbAdmin:

```
db.createRole({
  role: "backup_fix",
  privileges: [
     { resource: { db: "", collection: "system.profile" }, actions: [ "find"] },
  ],
  roles: [
  ]
})

db.grantRolesToUser("YOUR_BACKUP_USER", [{"role": "backup_fix", "db": "admin"}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The backup role you are using provides sufficient privileges to use the `MongoDB Management Service (MMS)` backup agent to use `mongodump` or to back up an entire `mongod instance`.

To backup a given database, you must have **read** access on the database.To backup the **system.profile** collection in a database, you must have **read** access on certain system collections in the database.

So in case you have `single instance` its enough to have the following role:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("backupUser", [{role: "dbAdmin", db:"admin"}])
```

Incase you maintain any `shard` or `replica` you can have the below role:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("backupUser", [{role: "clusterAdmin", db:"admin"}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the `dbAdmin` role to backup `system.profile`.

It might not be the best approach, but the error can be fixed by granting the dbAdminAnyDatabase role for the backup user.

```
db.grantRolesToUser("backupUser", [{role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db:"admin"}])
```